# Constructing a redox probe using an Arduino

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, analog, sensor, probe

I'm trying to design an ORP that can be used to measure the total voltage of a solution. This solution would be a NaCl solution that's mixed with water that can be anywhere from 0 to 5000 ppm of NaCl.

**I have multiple questions:**

1. What design should be used to make a redox probe/ORP that measures the voltage of the solution?
2. Secondly, how can I use the redox probe/ORP to find the ppm concentration of NaCl in the solution?

Comment: Have you done any research into this? There seems to be a fair number of ORP kits available. It seems to require little more than just a probe, a signal conditioning circuit, and a millvolt measurement. Here is an example of such a kit: https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Analog_ORP_Meter_SKU_SEN0165_    Even the signal conditioning circuit is available: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-ORP-sensor-signal-conditioning-circuit_fig15_305459550  .

Comment: Welcome to the list.  As already noted in the comments, to get good answers you should aim to demonstrate what research you have already done, with specific questions, rather than asking broad "how do I do X" questions.  Try editting you question based on you research to date.

Comment: Most likely using electrode potential, fellow SciOly competitor.